# Spring autowire configuration issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing an Spring application and I got a problem in spring autowire configuration. I am not able to solve that.

Here is my exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.venkatesh.service.ContactService com.venkatesh.controller.ContactsController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
```

Here is my Spring servlet.xml. I think problem is here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.venkatesh.controller"></context:component-scan>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.venkatesh.service"></context:component-scan>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.venkatesh.dao"></context:component-scan>


<bean id="jspViewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass"
value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
p:username="${jdbc:username}"></bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="configLocation">
<value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
</property>
<property name="configurationClass">
<value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you are using annotation based injection Can u post your java code how you actually trying..

Comment: Seems like you missed hibernate-*.jar in you lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says it all: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration`

Your missing one of Hibernate's Jar files or have the wrong version of hibernate.jar.  Make sure the `.jar` file is included on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

do you sure there is hibernate.jar in the classpath? unzip the hibernate.jar in your classpath to check if it contains  org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.class